# Mongoose, How to return data related to a Schema based on specific boolean flag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> Schema called `Restaurant` contain `isLive` flag.

How to return only restaurants that are contains `isLive` flag to `true`?

I don't want to check the `isLive` in every query or in every aggregation, like the following:

```
exports.getRestaurants = async (req, res) => {
  const restaurants = await Restaurant.getAllRestaurants();
  if (!restaurants) return next();
  const liveRestaurants = restaurants.filter(restaurant => restaurant.isLive);
  res.status(200).json({ restaurants: liveRestaurants });
};
```

What I want to do is to filter every operation related to `Restaurant` schema to `isLive = true`

What I tried to do is using the mongoose hooks but I didn't know how to return data based on the isLive flag.

```
restaurantSchema.pre('aggregate', function(next) {
  console.log('pre aggregate');
  // Return data based on the isLive flag,, is it possible?
  next();
});
```

So, Is it possible to return values based on the `isLive` flag using the hooks? or any other way can solve my problem?

Comment: Khaled did you check the answers? If any of them helped, please don't forget to mark it answer and upvote.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Sorry, I didn't check it yet, I will do ASAP. Thanks for you answer anw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [database view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) in MongoDB and add your `isLive` as a filtering condition.

```
Restaurant.db.createCollection('liveRestaurants', {
    viewOn: 'restaurants',
    pipeline: [{ $match: { isLive: true } }]
});
```

Then you need another model using the same schema:

```
let Restaurant = mongoose.model('Restaurant', restaurantSchema);
let LiveRestaurant = mongoose.model('liveRestaurants', restaurantSchema, 'liveRestaurants');
```

and you can query your read-only model the same way you query regular one but it will ony return filtered restaurants:

```
let result = await LiveRestaurant.find();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,, but can you explain why the third parameter for the mongoose.model is?

Comment: @KhaledRamadan it is a "collection name" which by default can be inferred from Model name but in this case we need to specify view name explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended you to use [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) method on your model:

```
exports.getRestaurants = async (req, res) => {
  const liveRestaurants = await Restaurant.find(name: 'isLive', true);
  if (!liveRestaurants) return next();
  res.status(200).json({ restaurants: liveRestaurants });
};
```

Comment: you are right, but my target from my question is to avoid the isLive checking in each query